# How to you specify a project version when executing SonarScanner without a properties file

Tags: linux, sonarqube, command-line-interface, version

In the .Net scanner you can specify the version in the cli using `/v:"1.0.1"`

But when I try to do this using the scanner for Linux it doesn't error but also doesn't work

`sonar-scanner -Dsonar.projectKey="my-project" -Dsonar.projectName="My Project" -Dsonar.host.url="https://mysonarqube.net" -Dsonar.login="968cc97907" -Dsonar.projectVersion:"1.0.1"`

I thought they mapped to the same thing, has anyone got any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You used a correct parameter, but the way of using it is incorrect. It should be `-Dsonar.projectVersion="1.0.1"` instead of `-Dsonar.projectVersion:"1.0.1"`.

Whole command:

```
sonar-scanner -Dsonar.projectKey="my-project" \
    -Dsonar.projectName="My Project" \
    -Dsonar.host.url="https://mysonarqube.net" \
    -Dsonar.login="968cc97907" \
    -Dsonar.projectVersion="1.0.1"
```